# Intel XDK Google + google services plugin - build fails

Tags: intel-xdk, cordova-3.5

I have developed a working hybrid application in which I am using "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin". This plugin needs as a dependency two other which downloads and installs automatically in the project. The dependencies are:
`com.google.playservices` and `plugin.http.request`

Using the Cordova-CLI, installing this plugin with the dependencies will fail building the project the 1st time because of a specific directory in the "playservices" plugin. To overcome this, I have to run "ant clean" in my project and also remove/rename that directory. Now, I am using Intel XDK and uploaded my app and installed most of my plugins successfully and run the application on my device. When I am trying to install the google play services plugin, it fails to build because of the reason I described above (I've run through the logs). How can I overcome this issue now? 
I have attached the part of the log that shows the fail error

```
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
 [echo] Handling aidl files...
 [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Handling Resources...
 [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
 [aapt] invalid resource directory name: .../App/platforms/android/com.google.playservices/google-play-services_lib/bin/res/crunch

BUILD FAILED
/Developer/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Developer/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 5 seconds
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: release,-f,.../App/platforms  /android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Command finished with error code 2: .../App/platforms/android/cordova/build --release
Error: .../App/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Developer/cordova/3.5.0-0.2.7/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When a build is run, the directory is cleaned after so the "ant clean" command won't be able to be used.  There will most likely have to be a fix made in the plugin itself to remove this requirement.  We made a fix in the Phonegap Facebook plugin.   Is this the plugin you are using ?  https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

Comment: Yes this is the plugin I am using. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to look into this today or next week.

Comment: FYI
I have managed to build successfully by downloading the plugin and firstly removing the directory that causes the issue. Then  I installed the plugin from a local directory.

Comment: I was able to build from the XDK fine.  Did you use the additions file to add the plugin?   <intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="google maps" intelxdk:value="https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin.git"> 
    <intelxdk:param intelxdk:name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" intelxdk:value="123456789" /> 
</intelxdk:plugin>

Comment: Yes I added the additions file and installed the maps plugin. The build was failing because of the crunch directory from one of the dependencies of this plugin (Google play services) as you can see from the log message in my question. I managed to build successfully too but after removing the crunch directory

Comment: I never got that directory.  I just added it from the additions file and it built fine.  Are you including any other plugins?

Comment: Yes I am using a few plugins. Using Cordova CLI, installing the google-map plugin will download and install automatically two more plugins (play-services and http-request). After installing the dependencies, Cordova failed to build (that is a known issue, check [here](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/issues/382)). For the same reason XDK was failing too. Strange you didn't get any errors, I' ll check it again by installing the plugin from start and see if it builds fine from the first time. Thanks for your interest